# Coffeescript Accessing a previously created object based on information in an array

Tags: arrays, object, coffeescript

I have started by creating a series of objects based on the information in an array but am later unable to use the array information to call back on the objects. This may just be a matter of getting the brackets right:

```
total = 0
for item in @timelineArray
    # This prints the object that was previously created
    console.log Opening

    # This prints the clip length for that object
    console.log Opening.getClipLengthOutMinusIn()

    # This prints the word Opening which is the first item in the timeline array
    console.log item.name

    # This yields an error "TypeError: Object Opening has no method 'getClipLengthOutMinusIn'"
    total += (item.name).getClipLengthOutMinusIn()
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: So you have a variable `Opening` in scope and then `item.name` will be the name (`Opening`) of that variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual way to solve the "how do I access a variable when its name is in a string" problem is to build your own namespace in an object:

```
names =
    Opening: whatever_Opening_was_set_to
    ...
```

and then you can access the values in `names` by name:

```
total += names[item.name].getClipLengthOutMinusIn()
```

You can also use [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) but that's almost always a horrible thing to do.